# Get the current/default value of TCP initcwnd on Linux

Tags: linux, tcp

I can manipulate such value with:

```
ip route change ... initcwnd 10
```

and then have a feedback with:

```
ip route show
```

But what about the default value before any modification? Is there a way to query that value from the system?

Alternatively, can you provide a **valid** reference that shows the default hardcoded value for each kernel version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[I don't really know for sure, but this seems like a legit reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hkchu-tcpm-initcwnd-01)

Hunch:

```
$ grep -A 2 initcwnd `find /usr/src/linux/include -type f -iname '*h'`
```

out:

```
/usr/src/linux/include/net/tcp.h:
/* TCP initial congestion window as per draft-hkchu-tcpm-initcwnd-01 */
#define TCP_INIT_CWND          10
```

Comment: Yes, grepping the code is always a good idea!

Answer (score 8):

Well, I can't say I'm 100 % sure this should be the answer, buuut, as it often comes, `ss` is the good choice to get some info revealed, for e. g.:

```
 ss -nli|fgrep cwnd
     westwood rto:1000 mss:536 cwnd:10
     westwood rto:1000 mss:536 cwnd:10
     westwood rto:1000 mss:536 cwnd:10
```

`-n` is typical to get rid of annoying DNS resolving, `-l` is we stick to listening sockets only and `-i` (the key) is "Show internal TCP information". As it can be seen, both congestion algorithm and default cwnd are shown.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for the initial value of the `snd_cwnd` parameter set when a TCP socket is initialized.

It looks like starting with linux kernel `2.6.39`, a macro `TCP_INIT_CWND` has been introduced in [linux/include/net/tcp.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/tcp.h?v=2.6.39) which populates the value of `snd_cwnd` when initializing a TCP socket.

I know where this code is in the kernel for `IPv4`, and unfortunately it does not seem to use any macro to populate the value for kernels older than `2.6.39`

```
/* net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c from 2.6.37 kernel */
static int tcp_v4_init_sock(struct sock *sk)
{
        struct inet_connection_sock *icsk = inet_csk(sk);
        struct tcp_sock *tp = tcp_sk(sk);

        ....
        ....
        ....

        /* So many TCP implementations out there (incorrectly) count the
         * initial SYN frame in their delayed-ACK and congestion control
         * algorithms that we must have the following bandaid to talk
         * efficiently to them.  -DaveM
         */
        tp->snd_cwnd = 2;

        ....
        ....
        ....
}
```

A similar init code exists for `IPv6` as well inside `tcp_v6_init_sock()` function in `net/ipv6/tcp_ipv6.c`